# How to group embedded form collection?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Imagine the following scenario: I have a `Order` that can contain one or more `Products`. Each product has (exactly) one `Category`, where that is just an attribute of the product. (As they're static I didn't see the necessity to put them into a separate entity.)

Now I embed those products as a collection into my order `FormType` [as documented in the Symfony3 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html):

```
$builder->add('products', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => ProductType::class
));
```

On my form, I want to group the product subforms/input fields by their category. Is there any–more or less–simple way to do so? E.g. by creating a custom form template? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would not use it in more than one place just place form separated on twig.

Don't use `form_widget()` for the related fields.

Simply do a loop and write your logic, you will be more flexible.

```
// view.html.twig
{% for key, field in form.children %}
    {# write your logic you may use form_widget here. #}
    {# also check field.vars or form.vars. #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Looks promising. Will take a deeper look into both approaches. It's important for me to use the native form validation, so I'll check if I can apply your answer.

Comment: I don't really get how I could use your second solution. Can you precise that a little? How could I use the grouping attribute to sepearate between groups?

Comment: ı'm in mobile now i will update when i get back home. ~ 3 hours

Comment: Can you advice how to implement your second solution (that looks very interesting). IMHO that can only be used to overwrite the entity form type blocks (as `integer` or `textarea`). I don't see how to use this in order to group form fields...?

Comment: Sorry for the late @GottliebNotschnabel I checked the docs, block_name would not be best for your case. In your case products are dynamic I missed that point https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/298 according to this issue dynamic block_name aren't allowed. `block_name` usage is not only provided for field types you can send block_name with field options and it is OK to put block_name to each separated field. You can provide for every field independent from it's field type. But in your case products are dynamic so there is no dynamic `block_name` sorry I marked as Second Solution.

Comment: No problem, I'll take that out of your answer (please rollback if disagree) and accept your answer.

Comment: But for the first solution, yeah it is not looks like clean idiom, It is more flexible you can solve your problem with little effort. If do you need any help with the first solution let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've successfully implemented your solution, but it works with two nested `for` loops (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dialogik/d325b4c68ef761d170e5)). Can you imagine a more efficient way?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I commented to related Gist. Could you check it please ?